# Best way to find out when old nginx configuration dropped all requests

Tags: django, nginx

I'm writing a 0dt deploy script for django.
When a deploy is made, it creates a new django server with the most recent code version, writes a new nginx config pointing to the right socket and reload nginx.

How do I find out when the old nginx workers replied all connections so I can drop the old django server?

Is looking at the workers pid the best option? I can't use nginx status url because the old config stops receiving connections.

Additionaly, there's another problem. Django is my backend, nginx is also proxying to a node server to serve the client. Is it possible to look at the active connections of a single upstream? Otherwise I will have to wait all connections to finish on the frontend too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in case anyone comes looking for it, I ended up with this solution:

```
 [...]
 # Run API
 echo ":: Starting new server"
 pm2 start ./server.sh --name api-$PRJ > /dev/null

 # Copy nginx config
 #echo ":: Swap nginx config"
 rm ~/nginx/api.atados.com.br.* 
 cp ~/deploy/api/nginx.conf ~/nginx/api.atados.com.br.$PRJ.conf
 perl -pi -e 's/{PRJ}/$PRJ/g' ~/nginx/api.atados.com.br.$PRJ.conf

 # Grab workers pid
 workers=`ps -aux | grep "nginx: worker" | sed "$ d" | awk '{print $2}'`

 # Reload nginx
 echo ":: Reloading nginx and waiting for old connections to drop."
 sudo service nginx reload > /dev/null

 # Wait for workers to die
 for job in $workers
 do
      while [ -e /proc/$job ]
      do
          sleep 1
      done
 done

 # Close old server
 pm2 list | grep api | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v $PRJ | xargs pm2 delete > /dev/null
 [...]
```